# Ruby Gems returns "command not found"

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Ubuntu 9.10

Just installed newgem

```
gem install newgem
```

and when i try

```
newgem new_project
```

I get

```
adam@adam-ubuntu:~$ newgem newproject
newgem: command not found
```

Ive checked my path via echo $PATH

```
adam@adam-ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/adam/.gem
```

and my gem enviroment

```
adam@adam-ubuntu:~$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/adam/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Im not hot with paths etc but all the gem directories listed above are on the path so how come it cant find the command?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Your `$PATH` variable needs to include the exact path to your Ruby's bin directory. Adding a directory to the `PATH` does not include it's subfolders. Try adding the bin directory via:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/adam/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin
```

or if you installed the gem using `sudo`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin
```

You might want to add this to your `.bashrc` file, so that you don't have to set this manually every time your open up a new bash.

Comment: ahh i was presuming that if i added /adam/.gem/ to the path then its subdirectories would automatically searched as well. dumb of me.

thanks for that

Comment: Note that on some versions of Ubuntu, the 1.8 gem bin path can be found at */var/lib/gems/1.8/bin*. This command is also handy for adding the sudo path to your bash profile *echo -e '\nexport PATH=$PATH:/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin' >>~/.bashrc*

Comment: You can find the exact patch by running "gem environment".  The EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY is the line you need.

Answer (score 14):

(Just stealing @John Franklin's comment)

```
$ gem environment
```

Will tell you the `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY`. Then put whatever that value is in your PATH like so (in your .bashrc or other shell config file).

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/bin"
```

Reload your shell and you should then be able to use the installed gem.

Comment: At last! Thank you for your theft :)

Answer (score 3):

If you use RVM (most do), then it will take care of this for you.  In fact putting it in your path directly may conflict.  You have to set a ruby to use though.  Run one of these on the command line.

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

or

```
rvm use --default 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

it happened to macOS Ventura 13.6.1,

and it works, when i add

`export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/bin:$PATH"`

in `.zshrc` file

- 3.3.0 is your gem version