# How to install and run "hanami new bookshelf" from zsh

Tags: ruby, macos, hanami

I installed the [Hanami](https://hanamirb.org/) gem and ran `hanami new bookshelf` but got

```
zsh: command not found: hanami
```

I'm running:

```
macos 10.15.1  
homebrew: 2.1.16  
ruby: 2.6.5p114  
rubygem: 3.0.6  
hanami: 1.3.3
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Output of `which hanami`?

Comment: `hanami not found` I'm using zsh.

Comment: How _exactly_ did you install it? Run `gem env` and copy/paste the output into your question, formatting it appropriately for readability. Don't use "edited" or "updated" tags to mark it because we can see what's changed.

Comment: Have you tried running `rehash` from the command-line?

Comment: I tried run `rehash` but no effect.

Comment: Sorry, I can't attach the output of `gem env`. How to do it? Edit the first post is always show errors... I'm not so much familiar with stack overflow...

Comment: This happens not only on one computer but also several, at least two. Do I need to install another application before the install the hanami gem?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here; with a fresh installed MacOS Sierra, ruby & etc.

`gem env` output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.5 (2019-10-01 patchlevel 114) [x86_64-darwin16]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/captainhusaynpenguin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/captainhusaynpenguin/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-16
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/captainhusaynpenguin/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

and finally, with the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392293/ruby-gems-returns-command-not-found) by rubiii:

adding the `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY` to PATH was the solution.

Quick command from above example:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin
```

For [permanently adding it to path](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#.Uydjga1dXDg):

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

was the fix.

Comment: Thank you! I see. I need add the EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: to PATH. Now I can run hanami command.

Comment: @tomoyuki-kosaka Yeah! of course!  I hope this edit has no errors,