# How to update danger

Tags: rubygems, danger

I'm facing a really weird issue and would appreciate any help.
When I run

```
danger --version
```

I get `4.3.5`

But when I run

```
gem list -a danger
```

I get

```
danger (8.2.3, 8.2.2)
```

And when I use `yes | gem uninstall -a --force danger` it uninstall `danger 8.2.2 and danger 8.2.3` but `danger --version` still gives `4.3.5`

danger exec is currently failing because it couldn't identify `android_lint` variable in the Dangerfile. And I think it's happening because of danger version.
How do I update it?

Comment: if you are on Linux you can check where danger is saved using `where` command.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm on ubuntu and I tried `whereis danger` which gave me  `/usr/local/bin`. Then I removed it from there using `su rm -rf danger`. But now `danger --version` gives `danger: not found`. Even when I'm install it using `gem install danger`

Comment: did you tried after closing terminal and then rerun the app in new terminal, and you are sure that you have gem directory in `PATH` env variable

Comment: you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392293/ruby-gems-returns-command-not-found) for gem path

Comment: is your problem solved

Comment: yes, it's solved. Thanks! You can post your answer and I'll accept it for bounty.

Answer (score 1):

If on Linux you can use `where` or `whereis` command to check where the binary is stored, then you can either backup, rename or delete if not required.

Then reinstall the `danger` gem and try to run the app

If still does not work open a new terminal and try to run the app in new terminal

And make sure `gem` directory is on your Path env variable

**Note:** For more info how to check gem directory path you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43187394/14475852)